# How can I delete properly an old translation string?

Tags: database, 9

I found an old string into `locales_source` table, like that:

[image]

The associated `8.5.3` version seems outdated.
I would like to understand the usefulness of the keep this data in my database ? How to clean it properly ?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, you could delete unnecessary strings in the UI.

Drupal 8 and 9 are missing this functionality; there is [an open bug report to add it back](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2503893), and hopefully it will eventually be fixed in Drupal 10.

There is a working patch in the issue to get a mostly working version of the function now.